# loop through variable with multiple results

Tags: jquery

I am trying to target some results of a loop that are stored in a variable and then append a button to the target result. What's happening here is that the button is being appended to every result.

```
$('.vehicles').each(function() {
  var priceText = $(this).find('PriceContainer > div > h3 > a > span').text();
  console.log(priceText);
  var button = '<button type="button">Click Me!</button>';
  if (priceText !== "Click for Quote!") {
    $(this).append(button);
  }
});
```

Comment: maybe use != instead of !== ?

Comment: What does your console say about that bit of code?

Comment: @justDan I'm getting the results of the console.log(priceText); no errors

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé didn't change anything

Comment: obviously this means priceText is never equal to 'Click for Quote!'... it would be easier if you could provide some html example...

Comment: There may be extra whitespace around the text, try using `.trim()` to remove it: `if (priceText.trim() !== "Click for Quote!")`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably extra whitespace around the text that you're not accounting for. You can use the `trim()` method to remove it.

```
$('.vehicles').each(function() {
  var priceText = $(this).find('PriceContainer > div > h3 > a > span').text().trim();
  console.log(priceText);
  var button = '<button type="button">Click Me!</button>';
  if (priceText !== "Click for Quote!") {
    $(this).append(button);
  }
});
```

You could also match the text in the selector instead.

```
var button = '<button type="button">Click Me!</button>';
$('.vehicles:has(PriceContainer > div > h3 > a > span:contains(Click for Quote!))').append(button);
```